# Tests validate data spring boot with Mock

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

My first method that I'm trying to validate, it receives an entity and gets the date to do the validation:

```
public boolean validaDataItem(RequestPedidoDTO requestPedidoDTO) {
    boolean valido = true;
    List<Item> itemDTOS = requestPedidoDTO.getItens();
    for (int i = 0; i < requestPedidoDTO.getItens().size(); i++) {
        valido = itemDTOS.get(i).getData_validade()
                .isBefore(itemDTOS.get(i).getData_criacao());
        if(itemDTOS.get(i).getData_criacao()
                .isAfter(itemDTOS.get(i).getData_validade())){
            throw new DataInvalidaException();
        }
    }
    return valido;
}
```

My second method that I'm trying to validate, it receives an entity and enters a list inside that entity to do the validation:

```
   public boolean validaDataOfertas(RequestPedidoDTO requestPedidoDTO) {
        boolean valido = true;
        List<Item> itemDTOS = requestPedidoDTO.getItens();
        for (int i = 0; i < requestPedidoDTO.getItens().size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < requestPedidoDTO.getItens().get(i).getOfertas().size(); j++) {
                valido = itemDTOS.get(i).getOfertas().get(j).getData_validade()
                        .isBefore(itemDTOS.get(i).getOfertas().get(j).getData_criacao());
                if (itemDTOS.get(i).getOfertas().get(j).getData_criacao()
                        .isAfter(itemDTOS.get(i).getOfertas().get(j).getData_validade())) {
                    throw new DataInvalidaException();
                }
            }
        }
        return valido;
    }
```

My entity requestPedidoDTO:

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class RequestPedidoDTO {

    @NotBlank
    @CPF(message = "CPF inválido! Deve seguir o padrão de 11 digitos")
    private String cpf;
    @NotNull @Positive
    private Double total;
    private List<@Valid Item> itens;

}
```

My entity Item:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Item {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String nome;
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime data_criacao;
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime data_validade;
    @NotNull @Positive
    private Double valor;
    @NotBlank
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Oferta> ofertas;


}
```

My entity Oferta:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Oferta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String nome;
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime data_criacao;
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime data_validade;
    @NotNull @Positive
    private Double desconto;
    @NotBlank
    private String descricao;

}
```

[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLfrF.png)

Additions I made to the test to make it work:

[test I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWijP.png)

Comment: Please add your unit test to your question, and explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: @tgdavies  i don't have any tests, this is the problem i don't know how to do it, i've never done unit tests... i'm trying to read some tutorials but i'm really not getting it

Comment: As the classes that the function you're testing on uses are simple DTOs there is no need to mock anything. Just instantiate DTOs which create the scenario you want to test and pass them to your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions do not need any mocks because they do not have any dependency on other classes, what you can do to unit test your functions is purely create an object of your entity and call the function with that entity, this will allow you to test your functions to be unit tested. Some examples of the unit tests you can write

1. **Check for `true` condition**

```
@Test
public void test_validaDataItem_true {
   RequestPedidoDTO requestPedidoDTO = new RequestPedidoDTO();
   //Initialize the object with a DTO that should return true
   boolean valid = validaDataItem(requestPedidoDTO);
   Assert.assertTrue(valid);
}
```

2. **Check for `false` condition**

```
@Test
public void test_validaDataItem_true {
   RequestPedidoDTO requestPedidoDTO = new RequestPedidoDTO();
   //Initialize the object with a DTO that should return false
   boolean valid = validaDataItem(requestPedidoDTO);
   Assert. assertFalse(valid);
}
```

3. **Check for `DataInvalidaException`**

```
@Test(expected=DataInvalidaException){
   RequestPedidoDTO requestPedidoDTO = new RequestPedidoDTO();
   //Initialize the object with a DTO that should throw a Data Invalid Exception
   validaDataItem(requestPedidoDTO);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, when I tried to run your test it gave an error =
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because the return value of "com.github.wezmoreira.avaliacao.dto.request.RequestPedidoDTO.getItens()" is null" 
so I tried to make some adjustments, it passed but it didn't check the whole method just part of it. I put the images in the post

Comment: Like I said, you don't need to mock the object to test your function, you can instead to do it by initializing the object like here -https://gist.github.com/SarahNaik1/2db191e2afacede98697743224876f79)

Comment: I ran your code and it gave error =
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because the return value of "com.github.avaliacao5.avaliacao.entities.Item.getOfertas()" is null

Comment: @meepo2k I have updated the code to set ofertas in the builder.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much, I still don't understand why it's working but I'm glad it finally worked!